# Ext.syncRequire() loading files recursively?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I want to require all the files after login. In my **controller** I have `views:[...views...]`, `stores: [...stores...]` and `models:[...models...]`.

My expectation was, if I `Ext.syncRequire('MyApp.controller.MyController');` that it will load *views*, *stores* and *models* inside that controller as well but my console says that it's loading views, stores and models *synchronously*.

If I put `Ext.syncRequire([controller, views, stores, models]);` I don't get the warning message again.

My question is, how can I load **just the controller** (synchronously) and I would get everything specified in the controller loaded as well (specified stores, models, views)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would only happen with dependencies defined in the `requires` array cause that is the only one the loader knows.

`views`, `models` and `stores` are only handled by the application class, meaning by a controller which get invoked by using the application instance. If you require a controller yourself there is nothing that will resolve these custom dependencies.

*Here is a way how it can be done*:

- Get the 'finish loading' callback to fetch the controller config from the classmanager.
- Build a new require list from the views,stores and models array.
- Load it and create the controller instance within the finish loading callback of this request.

Comment: So, your suggestion is to put everything in `requires: [stores, models, views]`?

Comment: @NullCod3 A controller is meant to be loaded by the application instance not by you. The reasons for all this lie deeper in the class and loader system of the framework and make sense. So yes, one solution would be adding all to the requires array for another see my edit.